# Authors posts on a author created page

Tags: pages, page-template, author

Any suggestions/ideas on how to get posts made by certain author to be displayed on a page that same author has created without using author.php?

To clear this up a bit, I have a site where author can create one page and multiple posts. Using normal author archives/pages do not offer the flexibility I need, so I'm looking for a way to have the authors' posts to be displayed on a page the author have created.

So "Matthew" creates a page named "Matthew" and every post he has made will be shown there. Everybody should be able to see the page as well.

Hopefully I made at least some sense with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a page called Matthew, then have a category called Matthew and have a plugin or something pull all posts form that Category?

That would quickly give you a solution without having to code anything.